# Add text literal to jquery input mask

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I'm using [jQuery Input Mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) and I'm setting a mask using `data-inputmask="'alias': 'integer', 'radixPoint': ',', 'rightAlign': false, 'allowMinus': false, 'allowPlus': false, 'autoGroup': true, 'groupSeparator': '.', 'autoUnmask': true"`

I want to add the text literal "km" after the value so the mask will be something like `15.000 km`

How can I do that? Is it possible to do it using just the data-inputmask attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of the property

> 'suffix': ' km'

Simple settings

```
<input style="text-align: right;" data-inputmask="'alias': 'numeric', 'groupSeparator': ',', 'autoGroup': true, 'digits': 2, 'digitsOptional': false, 'suffix': ' km', 'placeholder': '0'">
```

From your settings

```
<input style="text-align: right;" data-inputmask="'alias': 'numeric', 'rightAlign': false, 'allowMinus': false, 'allowPlus': false, 'autoGroup': true, 'groupSeparator': ',', 'autoUnmask': true, 'digits': 2, 'suffix': ' km', 'placeholder': '0', 'digitsOptional': false">
```